# Pythonのbugでしょうか？

Tags: python3, debugging

実現したい事。

ぱっと見では、

あり得ないだろうかも　知れない、
もしかしたら　Python開発者しか、
対処不可能かも　知れない、
挙動不振を、

何とかしたい。

_
概要、

Pythonで、

リストデータを　スライスして、
再結合する　コードを、
書きました。

_
しかし、

リストデーターが　たまに、
一部　ロストします、

必ず　ロストする訳でも、
必ず　保全される訳でも、
共に　ありません、

だからこそ　困っています。

_
しかも、

あり得ない　コード構成下で、
ロストします、

様々な　サイトに、
問い掛けましたが　解決しません、

手が　負えません、
デバッグを　お助けください。

_
環境、

ウィンドウズ１１　　22H2
Powershell　　　　　7.3.3
python　　　　　　　3.11×64bit
　　　　　　　　　　Microsoft配布版
Visual Studio Code　1.76.1

_
該当cord、

import対象cord、(iround.py)

```
import numpy as LAC # ListArrayControl
def iround(lis: list, dimensyon: int = 0, istypeint: bool = True):
    temp = (LAC.asarray(LAC.asarray((LAC.fabs((I := LAC.array(lis))) * (dimtemp := 10 **
            (0 - dimensyon + 1)) + 5) / 10, dtype=int), dtype=float) * LAC.sign(I)) / dimtemp * 10
    return LAC.asarray(temp, dtype=int) if (dimensyon > -1) and istypeint else temp
```

問題の　cord、

```
# coding: UTF-8
# python3.11

from logging import StreamHandler, FileHandler, getLogger, DEBUG, INFO, ERROR, Formatter, WARNING, CRITICAL
import pytest
import traceback as TB
import functools as FT
import itertools as IT
import math as MT
import random as RA
import numpy as LAC  # List Array Control.
import tqdm as PGR  # Progress rate.
from iround import iround
import sys


# Backtrace define section.
ERRORformatter = Formatter(
    "  Alert I I %(levelname)s   %(message)s %(asctime)s %(filename)s")
formatter = Formatter(
    "[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s - %(message)s (%(filename)s)")
logger = getLogger(__name__)

nomalhandler = FileHandler("DEBUG.log")
nomalhandler.setLevel(DEBUG)
nomalhandler.setFormatter(formatter)

WARNINGhandler = FileHandler("WARNING.log")
WARNINGhandler.setLevel(WARNING)
WARNINGhandler.setFormatter(formatter)

terminalhandler = StreamHandler()
terminalhandler.setLevel(ERROR)
terminalhandler.setFormatter(ERRORformatter)
logger.setLevel(DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(nomalhandler)
logger.addHandler(WARNINGhandler)
logger.addHandler(terminalhandler)


# Data definition section.
recursionlimit = sys.getrecursionlimit()
DisDataanomal = 0
E_Recursivecount = 0
Recursivemount = 3
C_Recursivecount = 0
C_Dataanomaly = 0
P_Dataanomaly = 0

# Unique random number routine.
#    Center-biased random number.
def Cran(end: int, start: int = 1, Centralization: int = 3):
    return iround([LAC.average(LAC.random.randint(start, end + 1,  Centralization))])[0]
    
    
    def list_action(action_times: int = 3, Orderlist: list = list(range(1, 55 + 1))):
    try:
        assert isinstance(Orderlist, (LAC.ndarray, list)) and not (isinstance(
            Orderlist[0], (LAC.ndarray, list)))
    except AssertionError:
        logger.debug(TB.format_exc)
    Orderlistlen = len(Orderlist)
    Spare_Orderlist = Orderlist

# Random biased on one side.
    def Eran2(end: int, start: int = 1):
        temporary1 = RA.randint(start, min(end, 4 + start) + 1)
        try:
            assert temporary1 >= start
        except AssertionError:
            logger.debug(TB.format_exc)
            logger.debug(
                f"Eran ŗ    l ُ픭   temporary1 = {temporary1}")
            return Eran2(end)
        except RecursionError:
#            E_Recursivecount += 1
            logger.warning(TB.format_exc)
            logger.warning(
                f"Eran ōċA Ăяo    {Recursivemount}   ₵ ܂   ")
            sys.setrecursionlimit(
                sys.getrecursionlimit() + Recursivemount)
        except MemoryError:
            logger.error(TB.format_exc)
            raise MemoryError
        return temporary1

# Overlap and integrate - routine.
    def Merements(target: list, removalside: list):
        temp1 = len(removalside)
        if temp1 < 3:
            target = removalside + target
            removalside = []
        else:
            temp2 = -Eran2(temp1)
            target = removalside[len(
                removalside) + temp2: len(removalside)] + target
            removalside = removalside[: temp2]
        return target, removalside

    for J in range(action_times):
        temp1 = Cran(len(Orderlist), Centralization=15)
        temporary1 = Orderlist[:temp1]
        temporary2 = Orderlist[temp1:]
        temporary3 = []
        while (len(temporary1) > 0) and (len(temporary2) > 0):
            temporary3, temporary1 = Merements(temporary3, temporary1)
            temporary3, temporary2 = Merements(temporary3, temporary2)
        Orderlist = temporary1 + temporary2 + temporary3
    try:
        assert Orderlistlen == len(Orderlist)
    except AssertionError:
        logger.warning(TB.format_exc)
        logger.warning(
            f"list_action Ńf [ ^ ُ픭   Orderlistlen = {len(Orderlist)}")
        Orderlist = list_action(Orderlist=Spare_Orderlist)
    except RecursionError:
        logger.warning(TB.format_exc)
        logger.warning(
            f"list_action ōċA Ăяo    {Recursivemount}   ₵ ܂   ")
        sys.setrecursionlimit(
            sys.getrecursionlimit() + Recursivemount)
    except MemoryError:
        logger.error(TB.format_exc)
        raise MemoryError
    return Orderlist


# Durability test routine.
def Durabilitytest(plactics: int):
    l = 0
    for j in PGR.tqdm(range(plactics)):
        l += (len(list_action()) != 55) + 0
    print(f"{l} {l / plactics * 100}%")


# main
Durabilitytest(10 ** 7)
```

_
試したこと

データ欠損異常が、

以下の　範囲で、
集中して　発生している事を、
突き止めました。

```
    def Merements(target: list, removalside: list):
        temp1 = len(removalside)
        if temp1 < 3:
            target = removalside + target
            removalside = []
        else:
            temp2 = -Eran2(temp1)
            target = removalside[len(
                removalside) + temp2: len(removalside)] + target
            removalside = removalside[: temp2]
        return target, removalside

    for J in range(action_times):
        temp1 = Cran(len(Orderlist), Centralization=15)
        temporary1 = Orderlist[:temp1]
        temporary2 = Orderlist[temp1:]
        temporary3 = []
        while (len(temporary1) > 0) and (len(temporary2) > 0):
            temporary3, temporary1 = Merements(temporary3, temporary1)
            temporary3, temporary2 = Merements(temporary3, temporary2)
        Orderlist = temporary1 + temporary2 + temporary3
```

_
所が、

弊者調査では　Merementsでは、
データ欠損が　起きない事が、
判明しています。

_
詰まりは、

調査が　正しいなら、
以下の　範囲で、
データ欠損が　発生している、
事となります。

```
    for J in range(action_times):
        temp1 = Cran(len(Orderlist), Centralization=15)
        temporary1 = Orderlist[:temp1]
        temporary2 = Orderlist[temp1:]
        temporary3 = []
        while (len(temporary1) > 0) and (len(temporary2) > 0):
          処理、
        Orderlist = temporary1 + temporary2 + temporary3
```

ちょっと　目を、
疑いますよね。

_
本当に、

此の範囲で　トラブルが、
あるなら、

其れは、
仕様の　問題が、
疑われ、

流石に　個人では、
特に　新規参入者には、
どうしようもないと　思います、

お助けを　頂けませんか？

_
補足情報、

※注：Warningを　大量に、
　　　ファイルに　吐き出します、
　　　お気を付けください。
*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/

Merementsルーチン検証用コーディングを、
追加します。

_
先ず、

Eran最大値は　検証結果上、
凡そ　6です。

_
其処で、

Eran値を　1〜7まで、
removalside要素数も 1要素数〜7要素数まで、
全て　総当たりで、
確認しました。

_
此でも尚、

お手元の　環境で、
oKが　出力されるようでしたら、
コーディング内容を　見られても、
お解り　頂けるように、

Merementsルーチンでの　データ欠損は、
起きない　事が、
確認　頂けるものと、
思います。

_
尚、

当該コードは　当方では、
ok以外の　出力が、
みられない　事が、
確認できています。

_
前記通り、

Merementsルーチンの　問題ではない、
事を、
納得　頂けますよね？

_
さて、

では　確認コードを、
テスト　頂き、
無関係な　発言は、
なきように　願えますか？

結構　無駄で、
手間なものでね。

```
j = 0
k = 0
Eran2 = lambda X: j
def test(func):
    pass
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        master = []
        global k, j
        for i in a:
            master.append(a)
            applicable = master
            for j in range(-1, -7, -1):
                temp1, temp2 = func([], applicable)
                k += 0 if len(master) == len(temp1) + len(temp2) else 1
        return
    return wrap
@test
def Merements(target: list, removalside: list):
    temp1 = len(removalside)
    if temp1 < 3:
        target = removalside + target
        removalside = []
    else:
        temp2 = -1 * Eran2(temp1)
        target = removalside[len(removalside) +
                             temp2: len(removalside)] + target
        removalside = removalside[: temp2]
    return target, removalside

print(str(k) if Merements([], []) else "ok")
```

Comment: "cord" は主に紐状のものを指す英語で、(プログラムの) コードは "code" です。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/q88q1b7nzgf2ck) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: 使用単語　失礼しました、
    ご指摘　有り難うございます。
    
    
    》予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうと
    
    其の点ですが、
    
    〉様々な　サイトに、
    　問い掛けましたが　解決しません、
    との　記載を、
    質問本文中から　ご確認を、
    頂けませんか？
    
    宜しく　願います。

Comment: 質問のタイトルには、概要が書かれていると良いです。バグなのかYes/Noの質問に見えますし、バグと主張するにはデータが足りないのでは。

Comment: 実は、

恐らく　アメリカ版キックスターターの、
モデレーター経験10年の方の、
プログを　投稿直前に、
拝見しましてね。


曰く、

・質問には　スキルが、
　求められる。
・質問か、バク報告か、
　解らない事が　困る。
要約すると　少なくとも、
此の　2つが、
書かれていました。

其処で、

私が　調べる限りでは、
あり得ない　所にしか、
異常部位可能性を、
認められませんでした関係で、

此の様な　タイトルと、
させて　頂いたのですよ。


例えば、

変えるとしたら　どの様な、
ものが　お勧めなのですか？

Comment: 不当編集の　却下に、感謝します。

Comment: 修正するなら、事前に　コメントとして、理由を　添えて、頂いて、相談してくださいね。

Comment: タグの `arraylist` は **Javaの標準ライブラリ** に関する話題に付けるべきタグで、Python の質問に付けるのは不適当です。

Comment: ご提案、ご配慮、有り難うございます、そういう　決まりなのでしたら、佐久署もありなのかも知れませんね。

Comment: ご提案、ご配慮、
有り難うございます、

そういう　決まりなのでしたら、
削除も　ありなのかも、
知れませんね。

_
しかし、

別タグで　Pythonとの、
指定が　ある中で、
Javaの　allayだよ、
と、

思う　方が、
果たして　居るでしょうか？

_
勿論、

Pythonでも　アレーでありますし、
此の際　現実に、
そぐあない　ものは、
改訂を　ご検討されては？
ご提案　致します。

Answer (score 3):

バグはここにあります：

```
temp2 = -Eran2(temp1)
```

結果が範囲外になる場合があります。
次のように置き換えてください:

```
temp2 = Eran2(temp1)
if (temp2 > len(removalside)):
    temp2 = len(removalside)
temp2 = -temp2
```

Comment: 先ずは、
_
感謝を　述べます、
有り難うございます。

_
さて、

どういう　事でしょう？　
どの様な　バグでしょう？

_
其処に、

もし　バグが、
あった場合でも、
其れは　Python側の、
致命的バグでは　ないのですか？

_
ご発言意図を、

詳しく　説明して、
頂けますか？　

_
先ずは、

貴方の　ご発言に、
傾聴したく　思います。　

_
但し、

〉其処に　バグはない、
　データ欠損は　起きない、
と、
言及している　事を、
お忘れに　ならないように、
お願いしたい。

Comment: 例えとして、

Eran2結果が　6、
removalsidet要素数残量が　3、
そうした場合ですら、
問題なく　動作する事が、
確認されて　いるのですが。

もしや　未確認うっかり突っ込み事故なのでしょうか？

Comment: お役に立ってよかった、あなたの例で：(temp2 = -6) ∧ (len(removalside) = 3) ⇒ (target = removalside[-3 : 3])。範囲内の負のインデックスは、Pythonでは意味があります、「-3」は「リストの末尾から3つの要素」を意味します。したがって、これはPythonのバグというよりも直感に反する動作です。わたくしはあなたの質問にうまく答えましたの？

Comment: 失礼ながら、

全く　役になは、
立てては　いません、
確認用コードを　提示します。

     removalside = [1,2,3]
     target = []
     temp1 = len(removalside)
     if temp1 < 3:
       target = removalside + target
       removalside = []
     else:
       temp2 = -6
       target = removalside[len(removalside) + temp2: len(removalside)] + target
       removalside = removalside[: temp2]
     print(target, removalside)

     removalside = [1,2]
     target = []
     temp1 = len(removalside)
     if temp1 < 3:
       target = removalside + target
       removalside = []
     else:
       temp2 = -6

Comment: target = removalside[len(removalside) + temp2: len(removalside)] + target
       removalside = removalside[: temp2]
     print(target, removalside)

Comment: わかりました。より良い回答を提供できるように努めたいと思いますわ。値が[1,2,3]の場合、removalside配列には3つの要素が含まれ、偶然にも(len(removalside)+temp2)は(-3)に等しく、最初の要素を指します。結果として、確認用コードの最初のブロックの結果は一貫しています。値が[1,2]のコードのもう1つのチャンクは、elseブロックを実行しないため、結果も一貫しています。確認用コードをremovalside=[1,2,3,4]に変更するとデータ欠損が再現され、結果はtarget=[3,4]になり、値1と2が失われます。これは、4つの要素があるためです、(len(removalside)+temp2)は(-2)となり、3番目の要素を指します。このケースを確認用コードに追加する必要があります。これがお役に立てば幸いです。

Comment: へ？　減らない　事を、確認して　投稿していますが？　何かの　間違えですか？　故意ですか？

Comment: 検証コードを　追加しましたので、確認を　頂けますか？　其処に　バグは、ありまさせんよ。

Comment: 更新ありがとうございます。検証コードをテストしました、「Merements」にバグがあることを確認しました。「Merements([], [])」は「None」に等しいため、出力は「ok」です、でもk=20です。kは次の場合にインクリメントされます:
(i = 3, j = -1);
(i = 3, j = -2);
(i = 4, j = -1);
(i = 4, j = -2);
(i = 4, j = -3);
(i = 5, j = -1);
(i = 5, j = -2);
(i = 5, j = -3);
(i = 5, j = -4);
(i = 6, j = -1);
(i = 6, j = -2);
(i = 6, j = -3);
(i = 6, j = -4);
(i = 6, j = -5);
(i = 7, j = -1);
(i = 7, j = -2);
(i = 7, j = -3);
(i = 7, j = -4);
(i = 7, j = -5);
(i = 7, j = -6);
問題が見つかってよかったので、私は戻る必要はありません。 良い続きを。

Comment: 訂正と、お詫び、